# Methods with event handling giving me errors

Tags: java, event-handling, mouseevent, key-events

Sorry for bad title but didn't know what else to say.
So I am trying to add a little piece of code into a game I am making so that you can make the player jump by pressing any key or using the mouse.  I pretty much copied the code that makes the player jump by pressing the mouse into the code that makes him jump by keyboard keys ( risky but I like to live on the edge) but it gives me the error:

```
The method KeyPressed(KeyEvent) from the type new KeyAdapter(){} is never used locally
```

from this:

```
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            player.jump();
        }

    }); 


this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        player.jump();
    }

}); 
}
```

I have searched the whole game but found no other things that have the word 'mouse' in them and I am also new to this. I'm sure i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: KeyPressed should be keyPressed (start with lower case).

Comment: Ah yes that was it.  I knew it would be a small mistake :/